# Finding a solution basis

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a real solution basis of $$y'=\left( \begin{matrix}-1&-2&0\\0&2&0\\-1&-3&2\\ \end{matrix} \right)y.$$

The characteristic equation of this matrix is $$P(t) = (1-t)(2-t)^2.$$
So next I calculated eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $1$ and $2$, which are $$u\overset{def}=(1,0,1) \text{ and }v\overset{def}=(0,0,1) \text{ respectively}.$$
The eigenvalue $2$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ but it only has one eigenvector. So if I'm correct we need a principal vector. I computed this and it is $$v_p\overset{def}=(2,-1,0).$$

Now the solution basis is $$B=\Big\{t\mapsto u e^t, t\mapsto ve^{2t}, ?? \Big\}.$$

My question is, what is the third function? What solution does the principal vector I have computed correspond to?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't your characteristic polynomial be $(1+t)(2-t)^2$?

Comment: You're right, sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the constant matrix $A$ of one such homogeneous system is [defective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix), for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ whose geometric multiplicity $m$ isn't big enough (i.e., it doesn't coincide with the algebraic multiplicity), the following functions are linearly independent solutions to the differential equation:

$$\begin{align} 
&t\mapsto e^{\lambda t}v_1\\ 
&t\mapsto e^{\lambda t}(tv_1+v_2)\\
&t\mapsto e^{\lambda t}\left(\dfrac{t^2}{2!}v_1+tv_2+v_3\right)\\
&t\mapsto e^{\lambda tv}\left(\dfrac{t^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}v_1+\ldots +tv_{m-1}+v_m\right),
\end{align}$$
where for each $i\in \{1, \ldots m\}$, $v_i$ is a [generalized eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) which can be found iteratively by solving the system $(A-\lambda I)v_i=v_{i-1}$ for $i\ge 2$ and $v_1$ being an eigenvector.

---

Assuming what you did is correct, you get a third solution (which makes the set of solutions linearly independent) by considering $t\mapsto e^{2t}(tv+w)$, where $w$ is a solution to $(A-2I)x=v$. I found one such solution to be $\begin{bmatrix} \frac 2 7 \\ -\frac 3 7\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

---

As [paw88789](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147810/paw88789) [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902791/finding-a-solution-basis/902844#comment1862355_902791), you have some mistakes in your solution, namely the computation of the characteristic polynomial which yields one wrong eigenvalue. Fortunately the part which pertains to your question is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir! Sorry about the mistakes.