# Solving the following system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following system of differential equations

1. $x' = a_{1}x+b_{1}y+c_{1}z$;
2. $y' = a_{2}x+b_{2}y+c_{2}z$;
3. $z' = a_{3}x+b_{3}y+c_{3}z$.

Do I need any specific conditions here?

First, I guess a solution, $x(t) = Ae^{rt}$, $y(t) = Be^{rt}$, and $z(t) = Ce^{rt}$.

Then substitute the solution in the system of DEs:

1. $rAe^{rt} = a_{1}Ae^{rt}+b_{1}Be^{rt}+c_{1}Ce^{rt}$;
2. $rBe^{rt} = a_{2}Ae^{rt}+b_{2}Be^{rt}+c_{2}Ce^{rt}$;
3. $rCe^{rt} = a_{3}Ae^{rt}+b_{3}Be^{rt}+c_{3}Ce^{rt}$.

Then the put the system of equations in a matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}-r &b_{1}  &c_{1} \\ a_{2}&b_{2}-1  &c_{2} \\ a_{3}&b_{3}  &c_{3}-r 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\ 
B\\ 
C
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$$.

The determinant of the 3X3 matrix yields the characteristic equation and after skipping some steps, we get:

$$r^{3} - (a_{1}+b_{2}+c_{3})r^{2} - (-a_{1}b_{2}-a_{1}c_{3}-b_{2}c_{3}+b_{3}c_{2}+a_{3}c_{1}+a_{2}b_{1})r-a_{1}b_{2}c_{3}+a_{1}b_{3}c_{2}+a_{3}b_{2}c_{1}+a_{2}b_{1}c_{3}-a_{3}b_{1}c_{2}-a_{2}c_{1}b_{3} = 0.$$

Now, where do I go from here, or is there a simpler way of doing the problem?

**EDIT:** Tried doing with the eigenvalues and eigenvalues but get the same thing and can't solve for the eigenvalues.

Comment: I'd say you're supposed to give the answer as a function of the eigenvalues of the associated matrix (which you'll just label $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ or something). Otherwise this is hell.

Comment: @GitGud We weren't even taught about the eigenvalues.

Comment: @user36829: What techniques have you been taught?

Comment: Perhaps it's a prerequisite? They certainly help and I could go as far as saying they are necessary, but I won't. By the way, your guess at a solution is only right if there are three distinct eigenvalues, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @science Well, it's not really a DE class per se. It's a first-year PhD economics class called Dynamic Optimization. And you know how economists do math ... we haven't been taught any formal techniques actually. Just guesswork to find the solution.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~dummit/docs/diffeq_3_systems_of_linear_diffeq.pdf).

Comment: Just correcting myself. I misread the exponents of $x(t), y(z), z(t)$. Your try at the moment will never work.

Comment: @GitGud I'm learning the method with the eigenvalues and will do it myself. Meanwhile feel free to post your solution if you want to.

Comment: I'm much more interested in the solution your instructor has in mind. In any case my solution would be a small generalization of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902791/finding-a-solution-basis/902844#902844).

Comment: I'd just let $\mathbf{v}(t)= \exp(t\mathbf{A})\mathbf{v}(0)$, and leave it at that.

Comment: I'll make an edit soon.

Comment: Even with the eigenvalues I am getting nowhere.

Comment: @user36829 What Nick said. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744296/differential-equations-diagonalizable-matrix/744324#744324).

Comment: @user36829 Yo. I want to help you, but I can't understand what kind of answer your instructor wants. An answer depending on $A$'s entries is completely unreasonable. And since you don't seem to have any tools are your disposal, we're left with nothing to go on.How do you usually solve systems of differential equations?